# Find and hide file extension

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I am trying to find all files that have the same filename (excluding the file extension) that occur 3 times. I  also need the full path to the file.

What I have currently is

```
#get file without extension
alias lse="ls -1R | sed -e 's/\.[a-zA-Z]*$//'"
#print out the current dir and get files occuring 3 times
lse | sed "s;^;`pwd`/;"  | sort | uniq -c | grep " 3 "
```

This runs howver `pwd` prints the folder I ran the command from not the path to the file.

So I tried `find`

```
find . -type f | sed "s#^.#$(pwd)#" | sort | uniq -c
```

This runs but includes the file extension. When I try to add `sed -e 's/\.[a-zA-Z]*$//'"`
  I get errors as I am not sure how to combine the two sed commands and I cannot seem to pipe a second time to sed?

so what I am trying to do is

```
find . -type f | sed "s#^.#$(pwd)#" | sed -e 's/\.[a-zA-Z]*$//'"| sort | uniq -c | grep " 3 "
```

but this does not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what's the extra " in the second sed command doing there?

```
 /tmp/test $ touch foo.bar foo.baz foo.foo
 /tmp/test $ find . -type f | sed "s#^.#$(pwd)#" | sed -e 's/\.[a-zA-Z]*$//'| sort | uniq -c | grep " 3 "
 3 /tmp/test/foo
```

Comment: Note that `grep " 3 "` can cause issues with files like ` 3 .txt` (space before and after 3). You can replace it with `awk '{if ($1 == 3) {print}}'` (but check what the awk default separator for your system is)

Answer (score 1):

Alternate but similar way using some other concepts:

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n' | sed 's/\.[[:alpha:]]*$//' |\
sort | uniq -c | awk '$1==3'
```

Uses:

- `find`'s `-printf` to directly strip the leading directories.
- the `[:alpha:]` character class to define letters. This emulates your example, but does not take into account file endings with numbers (e.g. `.mp3`). Change to `[:alnum:]` to match letters AND numbers. Look for more info on character classes to see other possibilities.
- `awk` to only print the lines with count 3 (easily changed to `count>=3` which seems more logical). Since `print` is the default action, this can be accomplished using only `awk '$1==3'`.